# What is this tool called?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools

I'm looking for a tool or a filter that closely resembles how this looks, it transforms the layer kinda of like a smudge tool but again I'm not sure what its called or where it's found.[image]
any help?

Answer (score 1):

At least two are easy to suggest:

1. Edit > Transform > Warp
2. Filter > Liquify

They can be applied to a selection or whole layer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the Perspective Warp tool. Edit>Perspective Warp

Starting out in Layout mode, click to add as many Perspective planes as you want. Move all the points where you need them, then hit the Warp button to enter Warp mode.

Now you can adjust all your points and it will adjust the image in a similar fashion to the smudge tool.